# What's a reliable way to detect math mode (including align*)?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, conditionals

I thought `\ifmmode` detected math mode, but clearly it does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \ifmmode math \else not math \fi
\]
$\ifmmode math \else not math \fi$
\begin{align*}
  \ifmmode math \else not math \fi
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I reliably detect math mode, including within `align*`?

Comment: Strangely enough, if I add `\relax` before `\ifmmode`, then it works fine...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding `\relax`, as you noted in the comment, is the solution basically.  If you look at the LaTeX sources you'll see that most uses of `\ifmmode` are preceded by `\relax`, exactly for that reason:

```latex
\def\verb{\relax\ifmmode\hbox\else\leavevmode\null\fi %[...]
```

At the beginning of a table cell (roughly what `align` uses) TeX is expanding macros looking for `\omit` or `\noalign`, and at this point it's *not* in math mode, and expands `\ifmmode` which is then false.

Adding `\relax` (or any non-expandable token) stops that scanning, and the column template is inserted, effectively starting math mode.

Comment: Hi, I believe you meant `\noalign` instead of `\span` (in case this is after a `\cr`; otherwise, only `\omit`). cf. TeXbook pp. 240 and 248. :-)

Comment: @frougon Ah, right, thanks!  Not sure why I thought of `\span`